# Psycopg2: making a query in python using with ... as

Tags: python, psycopg2, with-statement

Which is the best pattern to make a query with psycopg2?

This one:

```
# get_connection is a function that returns a connection to the db.
with get_connection() as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table")

or simply this:

with get_connection() as conn:
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that psycopg2 objects don't implement the __exit__ function, so they can't be used to declare a with block!

Comment: This has been implemented. Version 2.5 (April 2013) was the first release to use context managers, so `with` blocks are now allowed.

Answer (score 4):

You can now use `with` for psycopg2 connections and cursors, starting with version 2.5. The documentation is [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#with-statement).

It mentions:

> When a connection exits the with block, if no exception has been
>   raised by the block, the transaction is committed. In case of
>   exception the transaction is rolled back.

Therefore, I think your first code snippet above using the nested `with` blocks is the better pattern.